# PHP concatenate and differentiate?

Tags: php

I am using this code to get id from database:

```
$selected_event_ids .= $get_event_id;
```

and the coming output is:`1149`

but we want the output like: `11,4,9`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

try this

```
for() { // in loop
    $selected_event_ids[] = $get_event_id;
}

echo implode(',',$selected_event_ids);
```

Answer (score 1):

it should be:

```
while($get_event_id = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $selected_event_ids[] = $get_event_id['row_name'];
}

echo implode(',',$selected_event_ids);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$selected_event_ids .= $get_event_id.",";
```

you will have output like 11,4,9,

then you need to truncate the last extra comma with this

```
$selected_event_ids = substr($selected_event_ids,0,strlen($selected_event_ids)-1);
```